# How to get n data from table in laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, controller

I want to get only 5  data from user table

I try to write `User::where("","")->get(5);` but seems not working.

Comment: ___Not working?___ Thats not a helpful description. Do you get NONE or do you get 6 or do you get 2?

Comment: Just use `->take(5);` instead of `get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use instead:

```
User::query()->take(5)->get();
```

Or if with where condition:

```
User::query()->where("column", "value")->take(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this

```
User::where("","")->take(5)->get();
```

Reference: [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#building-queries)

For the next time please describe your question with more information